# How to make the window close button to perform as quitting the program in object c?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to object c, and I'm coding a Mac app by object c. I just find that by default, the close window button, which is the green x button on the left corner, is only for closing the window frame. So how to make it actually quit the program when it is clicked? (I know that in Java swing JFrame, there's a method called default closing option.) BTW, I'm using NSWindow as my main UI.

Comment: This is inadvisable. On Mac OS X applications should not quit when the last window is closed, the process should only terminate after the user chooses the Quit item from the Application menu.

Answer (score 2):

Your application delegate should implement `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` and return the desired response. See:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/

Comment: So how to actually implement it? I added applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed method into my NSWindow.m, but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You need to create an object which implements `NSApplicationDelegate`. That object needs to implement your version of `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed`. Then you set an instance of this object as the delegate to your NSApp via `setDelegate`. See https://github.com/fzwoch/mincer/blob/2d3b3a1b5249c21a1e54abe0bd96da6892e0c2fc/mincer.m for an example. The object is question is `AppDelegate`here.